# can't get payum paypal express checkout recurring payment work with tax

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, payum

In my symfony2 application, I am using payum paypal express checkout to perform recurring payments.

I'm following instructions here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

I want to add item details but I can't get to make it work when I put tax information. I get the payum error :

```
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 =>  Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_LONGMESSAGE0  =>  The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
```

I've been playing around with tax amounts but I couldn't make it work.
If i remove all tax information, everything goes fine and I'm redirected to paypal with right amounts. How can I configure my payment to make it work ?

Please see below the details parameters sent to paypal:

```
array(14
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0    =>  Compte utilisateur
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0  =>  46
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0    =>  Abonnement pour 1 Compte utilisateur(s) pour 19.00â‚¬ / mois
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 =>  19
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0  =>  3.8
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 =>  1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT =>  3.8
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE   =>  EUR
NOSHIPPING  =>  1
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT    =>  22.8
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT    =>  22.8
subscription_type   =>  mensual
L_BILLINGTYPE0  =>  RecurringPayments
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0  =>  Abonnement mensuel FoodMeUp
)
```

and a dump of payum answer:

```
array(28
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0    =>  Compte utilisateur
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0  =>  46
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0    =>  Abonnement pour 1 Compte utilisateur(s) pour 19.00€ / mois
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 =>  19
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0  =>  3.8
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 =>  1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT =>  3.8
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE   =>  EUR
NOSHIPPING  =>  1
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT    =>  22.8
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT    =>  22.8
subscription_type   =>  mensual
L_BILLINGTYPE0  =>  RecurringPayments
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0  =>  Abonnement mensuel FoodMeUp
INVNUM  =>  55004be1633b4
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION  =>  Sale
RETURNURL   =>  http://foodmeup.dev/app_dev.php/payment/capture/NRil21P5mhVC93qman2D_k4al_xeFd-MfnHHYyqVxYQ
CANCELURL   =>  http://foodmeup.dev/app_dev.php/payment/capture/NRil21P5mhVC93qman2D_k4al_xeFd-MfnHHYyqVxYQ
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL  =>  http://foodmeup.dev/app_dev.php/payment/notify/rRD65dqHU-TSgXyBdW8eJkGdMx6CiCFVOq8BZ8PTBt4
TIMESTAMP   =>  2015-03-11T14:06:29Z
CORRELATIONID   =>  193dfdd411684
ACK =>  Failure
VERSION =>  65.1
BUILD   =>  15735246
L_ERRORCODE0    =>  10413
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 =>  Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_LONGMESSAGE0  =>  The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
L_SEVERITYCODE0 =>  Error
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I use following code for send payment request on PayPal (I use https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php):

```
    $paymentDetails = new EBLBaseComponents\PaymentDetailsType();

    foreach ($paymentData['items'] as $key => $item) {
        $itemDetails = new EBLBaseComponents\PaymentDetailsItemType();
        $itemDetails->Name = $item['name'];
        $itemDetails->Amount =  new CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType($paymentData['currency'], $item['amount']);Order item price
        $itemDetails->Quantity = $item['quantity'];
        $itemDetails->ItemCategory = $item['category'];

        if ($item['tax']) {
            $itemDetails->Tax = new CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType($paymentData['currency'], $item['tax']); //Order item tax
        }
        $paymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem[$key] = $itemDetails;
    }

    $paymentDetails->OrderTotal = new CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType($paymentData['currency'],  $paymentData['total']);//Order total
    $paymentDetails->PaymentAction = 'Sale';
    $paymentDetails->ItemTotal = new CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType($paymentData['currency'],  $paymentData['subtotal']); //Order subtotal

    $paymentDetails->TaxTotal = new CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType($paymentData['currency'], $paymentData['tax']);//Order total tax


    $setECReqDetails = new EBLBaseComponents\SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
    $setECReqDetails->PaymentDetails[0] = $paymentDetails;
    $setECReqDetails->CancelURL = $paymentData['cancelUrl'];
    $setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = $paymentData['returnUrl'];
    $setECReqDetails->ReqConfirmShipping = 0;
    $setECReqDetails->NoShipping = 1;

    $setECReqType = new PayPalAPI\SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
    $setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

    $setECReq = new PayPalAPI\SetExpressCheckoutReq();
    $setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;

    try {
        /** @var PayPalAPI\SetExpressCheckoutResponseType $setECResponse */
        $setECResponse = $this->paypal->SetExpressCheckout(
            $setECReq
        );
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $data = array('result' => 'failed');
        $data['errors'] = $this->processConnectionException($ex);

        return $data;
    }
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: hmmm, unfortunately there is too much api specific code here, I don't get to see how paypal parameters are used.

Comment: It is not Payum issue. The Paypal does the check on total price fields. It sums up all items prices + taxes and so on and it has to be equal to total price.

Comment: In my code you can see example of correct use of PayPal API with PayPal Merchant SDK with taxes.

Could you show part of your code which you use for payment?